# When to include a variable as a mediator or a predictor

Tags: mediation

I'm trying to understand the different models for investigating a variable of interest (mindfulness facets) against an outcome variable (anxiety). I notice that there are two possible ways for me to investigate this but I'm having trouble understanding why you would choose one model over the other, or what the difference is in what these models would tell me about the mindfulness facets?

For example if I want to find out more about the relationship between specific facets of trait mindfulness (such as 'Acting with Awareness') and Anxiety. What are the reasons for;

1. including mindfulness as the mediator between known predictors of anxiety (such as Dysfunctional beliefs, as the IV) and anxiety (as the DV)?

   'dysfunctional beliefs' ----> 'trait mindfulness' -------> anxiety
2. including trait mindfulness as the predictor and anxiety as the outcome variable?

   'trait mindfulness' -------> anxiety
3. including 'dysfunctional beliefs' as the mediator between trait mindfulness and anxiety?

   'trait mindfulness'------> 'dysfunctional beliefs' -------> anxiety

My supervisor is encouraging me to undertake the first example, with 'trait mindfulness' as the mediator, as he argues that mindfulness in this example *explains the process by which* 'dysfunctional beliefs' result in 'anxiety' - however my understanding is that the mediation model suggests a causal relationship and my argument here would be that low trait mindfulness causes 'dysfunctional beliefs' which result in 'anxiety', not that dysfunctional beliefs cause trait mindfulness..

Alternatively is mediation not the right way to be thinking about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try not to think of it as x causes m causes y; rather, there are relationships (positive or negative) between all 3 variables, and we may hypothetically predict these relationships based on theory and literature. So for your proposed mediation: 1) people with low trait mindfulness experience greater anxiety (X-Y). 2) we may suggest that low TM predicts negative beliefs (X-M); and 3) negative beliefs may predict greater anxiety (M-Y). Is the relationship between TM and anxiety better explained by negative beliefs? While you are correct that the IV has to precede the mediator temporally in the causal sequence (see MacKinnon, Fairchild, & Fritz, 2007). One might argue that depending on what the belief is, it developmentally occurred before mindful awareness and attention. I don't know how trait mindfulness is measured, but it may be hard to explain the variability between trait mindfulness vs. skilled practice? Something to think about.

You could think of trait mindfulness as a moderator in the relationship between dysfunctional beliefs and anxiety. Whereas trait mindfulness interacts with beliefs on various levels and perhaps provides a buffering effect for anxiety.

Ultimately I think you can make a case for any of these models. It comes down to what variable you believe better explains the existing relationship :) Good luck!